# Can't get address from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, maps

I have this code, it should work but when I call it to get address returned it stops my application, here's the code I have:

```
public String getLocation()
        {
            String address = "";

            if(loc!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Address ads = geo.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1).get(0);

                    address+= ads.getAddressLine(0)+", ";
                    if(ads.getAdminArea()!=null)
                    {
                        address+= ads.getAdminArea()+", ";
                    }
                    else if(ads.getLocality()!=null)
                    {
                        address+= ads.getLocality()+", ";
                    }
                    address+= ads.getCountryName()+".";

                }
                catch(IOException IOex)
                {
                    address = " las coordenadas en el siguiente link. Estoy sin internet";
                }
                address += " http://maps.google.com/?q="+loc.getLatitude()+","+loc.getLongitude();
                return address;
            }
            else
            {
                return "/";
            }

        }
```

I have this code working on another application, I don't know what is going on here, if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add your logs from your logcat :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look at the **log** of Eclipse or anything else that you are currently using. 
It pretty easy to read from the **log** what is wrong - especially when it's a NULL.

Second, I have some doubts about this code.

I would suppose that getAddressLine and getCountryName are NULL's because adress cannot be decode.
Please check it. 
You can do System.out.println("something"); to prints information to Console.

Third:
Maybe **geo** is not initalized? Like not only: Geocoder geo but Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(currentContext);

And the last hint, geocoding things should be done as ASyncTask - because it's (ASyncTask) is always starting new Thread and not froze UI thread.

Here some examples without ASync implemented but very similar to your code:

```
public class GeocodingTasks {

private Context appContext;
private Geocoder coder;

public GeocodingTasks(Context c) {
    this.appContext = c;
    this.coder = new Geocoder(c);
}

public Location getLocationFromAddress(String enteredAddress){

    List<Address> address;  
    Location currentlyAdding = new Location(enteredAddress);

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(enteredAddress,1);

        if (address != null && address.size() > 0) {    
            Address currentLocation = address.get(0);
            currentlyAdding.setLatitude(currentLocation.getLatitude());
            currentlyAdding.setLongitude(currentLocation.getLongitude());   

            Toast.makeText(appContext, 
                    "You have added place: " + enteredAddress,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            return currentlyAdding;
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {}

    return null;
}}
```